# Can't generate absolute path using URL::to() in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I wanted to give my stylesheet an absolute path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css/styles.css') }}">
```

the stylesheet can't be loaded . when i use `href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}"`
 it works just fine but  when i  use the facade URL::to() it doesn't load .

Comment: Why not just use the `asset()` helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL::to()` will return an absolute path. Do you have `index.php` in your url? In your example, the only real difference between `URL::to()` and `asset()` is that the `asset()` method will remove any reference to `index.php`, but `URL::to()` won't.

If you want to use the `URL` facade instead of the global helper methods, I would suggest using `URL::asset()` instead of `URL::to()`. That is the function specific for loading assets, and is actually what the `asset()` helper function calls.

Answer (score -1):

let's try it will work

```
do this:
set your url in app/config/app.php

then initiate URL:
URL::forceRootUrl(Config::get('app.url'));

so you will get the URL by:
url('/);
```